# Is there a more efficient method to archive my double-loop case?

Tags: javascript, math

Is there a more efficient method to archive my double-loop case?

I have two JavaScript object, if the second has the key as same as the first object, then it should assign the value to it.

```
var obj_01 = {
  a: '',
  b: '',
  c: ''
}

var obj_02 = {
  a: '1',
  b: '2',
  c: '3',
  d: '4',
  e: '5'
}

for(item_b in obj_02){
  for(item_a in obj_01) {
    if(item_a === item_b){
      obj_01[item_a] = obj_02[item_b]
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj_02, obj_01)
```

You see, I have the double-loop method to get my requirement, but whether there is a more efficient way to archive it?

Comment: You just need one loop. You can use `o1.hasOwnProperty(item_b)` to check whether a property exists in `o1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(item_b in obj_02){
    if(obj_01.hasOwnProperty(item_b)) {
        obj_01[item_b] = obj_02[item_b]
    }
}
```